# Error when trying to install a gatsby plugin

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When trying to install `plugin-gatsby-react-helment`  getting the following error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsproject@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: gatsby@3.14.6
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^3.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^4.0.0-next" from gatsby-plugin-react-helmet@5.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet
npm ERR!   gatsby-plugin-react-helmet@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.    
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-24T14_44_33_845Z-debug.log
```

but react-helmet just install fine
I am clueless

Comment: It may be coming from your cache. go to this directory ( C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\ ) and remove "npm-cache" then try again

Answer (score 2):

It's quite self-explanatory.

You have installed a Gatsby version `^3.11.1` as it is extracted from:

```
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^3.11.1" from the root project
```

While `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` as is, without a specific version tries to install the latest one (`5.4.0`). This latest version requires a Gatbsby version 4 onwards (major update) as it is extracted from:

```
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^4.0.0-next" from gatsby-plugin-react-helmet@5.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet
npm ERR!   gatsby-plugin-react-helmet@"*" from the root project
```

That said, depending on your specifications you have two options:

- Upgrading the whole Gatsby project to 4: follow the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v3-to-v4/)
- Installing a specific compatible `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` version by running:

  ```
    npm install gatsby-plugin-react-helmet@4.14.0
  ```

  *Note 1:  Check the `4.14.0` details (or others) in the [`CHANGELOG.md`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/CHANGELOG.md)*

  *Note 2: Check the `@` syntax details at: https://nodejs.dev/learn/install-an-older-version-of-an-npm-package*

The second one will have a lower impact in your project but ideally, sooner or later you will need to upgrade the Gatsby version.

I guess, being a lower major update any version 4 of the `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` plugin should work. If not, try lowering the version.

Remember to clean the cache (with `gatsby clean`) in each trial.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error recently. Here's how you can fix it

1. Delete `package-lock.json`
2. Goto gatsby folder path and run `gatsby develop` or run `npm i`

If it doesn't work, delete node modules and try the above steps again